Page Break using Javascript Jquery in view and Print
I have this code which I want to use pagebreak when the data in the first page is overlap in must goes to the next page since the size of my container-body3 paper is A4 and I tried dynamically but it didn't work until, can someone help me with this? Now Im out of option

Updated I provided example of my snippet but the problem is when content 2 data is overlapping it didn't create third content


      function handleOverflow() {
        const pageHeight = 297; // A4 height in mm
        const containerWrapper = document.getElementById('container-wrapper');
        const containerBodies = document.querySelectorAll('.container-body');
        const firstContainer = containerBodies[0];
        const tableBody = document.getElementById('table-body');
        
        // Function to create a new container
        function createNewContainer() {
          const newContainer = document.createElement('div');
          newContainer.classList.add('container-body');

          // Clone the table structure (thead, tfoot)
          const newTable = document.createElement('table');
          newTable.innerHTML = firstContainer.querySelector('table').innerHTML;
          
          // Empty tbody for the new container
          newTable.querySelector('tbody').innerHTML = '';
          newContainer.appendChild(newTable);
          return newContainer;
        }

        let currentContainer = firstContainer;
        let newContainer = null;
        
        // Move overflowing rows to new containers
        while (currentContainer.scrollHeight > currentContainer.clientHeight) {
          if (!newContainer) {
            newContainer = createNewContainer();
            containerWrapper.appendChild(newContainer);
          }
          
          // Move last row from current container to new container
          const lastRow = tableBody.lastElementChild;
          newContainer.querySelector('tbody').prepend(lastRow);
          
          // Check the height again
          if (currentContainer.scrollHeight <= currentContainer.clientHeight) {
            // Reset for the next potential overflow check
            newContainer = null;
          }
        }
      }

      // Wait for DOM content to load, then handle overflow
      window.onload = handleOverflow;
     .container-body {
        width: 210mm;
        height: 297mm;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        position: relative;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }

      th, td {
        border: 2px solid navy;
        padding: 8px;
        text-align: left;
      }

      thead {
        display: table-header-group;
      }

      tfoot {
        display: table-footer-group;
      }

      tr {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
      }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="container-wrapper">
      <div class="container-body">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>This is the table header</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td>This is the table footer</td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
          <tbody id="table-body">
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
   </body>
   <html>



